# svn pre-revprop-changes error

Tags: svn, svnsync

I am already at my wits end. I have this problem for 2days now and the answers that I came up with have no effect. I searched over the net for possible solutions and did some of those, still no effect. I saw some answers but they are in linux and I dont know what commands to use if I'm gonna do those in windows.

I want to sync two repositories. I followed procedures from [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2009/03/11/mirroring-subversion-from-windows.aspx) as well as from [here also](http://www.cardinalpath.com/how-to-use-svnsync-to-create-a-mirror-backup-of-your-subversion-repository/).

Here's the error that I'm getting:
`svnsync: E165006: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;`

I already edited the pre-revprop-change hook and here's what I added:

```
IF "%3" == "sync_user" (goto :label1) else (echo "Only sync_user can make changes">&amp;2) 
exit1
:label1
exit 0
```

I already changed the permission of one of the repos but I still get that error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pre-revprop-change hook must be named (in case of Windows) `pre-revprop-change.bat` in order to enable OS to execute it.